# Compiling zbar library for 32 bit microcontroller with no heap

Tags: c, microcontroller, cortex-m, zbar

I want to port zbar to a microcontroller that doesnt have a heap, would zbar work if I statically allocate it? Or does it require a heap? I can look into adding a help but what size of heap is required for zbar?

Has anyone else ported this for a 32 bit micro, such as the Cortex-M1.

Looking at the code there are quite a bit of mallocs in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could change library and remove mallocs, but same question will be present "what size is required" for new statically allocated memory.

Easier way to go is to set compiler to use heap. If you don't know the size required for the library only approach is "try and error". Unfortunately there is no guaranties that it will work in any use case. Best you can do once when you know what size of memory is available (not used by the application), allocate as much as possible for the heap.